# java: figuring out origin package of missing symbol

Tags: java, maven, ant, import, dependencies

I'm noticing that most Java web dev tutorials I come by are designed for people using an IDE and/or Maven instead of the Ant/text-editor combo that I use.

I've learned to determine where the `POM.xml` excerpts download the deps by using http://mvnrepository.com/, but I'm still having a hard time determining the proper import statements when the tutorial omits them.

Sometimes, I've found that [even if I find the docs, I may find that there's no obvious way to determine a symbol's package of origin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrns/). *(try to find out which package @Produces belongs to)*.

So, here's the scenario: you try to compile and you find out there's a missing symbol and you have no idea where that symbol is supposed to come from.  What do you do?
Other than chasing geese on Google all day, how do I determine the import statement when it's missing from the tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

#### EDIT:

I've figured out that I can construct an import statement by using the file hierarchy in the unzipped jar file ( for instance, `jersey-multipart-1.19/com/sun/jersey/multipart` becomes `import com.sun.jersey.multipart.*` ).  But that still doesn't necessarily tell me how to go the other direction, e.g. to find out where `@Produces` is defined.

Comment: I'm having cold feet about asking this question. Is it one of those things where "if you don't know where a package comes from, you shouldn't be trusted to use it"?

Answer (score 1):

During development one can use the search index that comes with Maven Central to find the modules containing missing classes:

http://search.maven.org/

Better yet, deploy a local Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi). These would mirror Maven central's index and also index any local jars you might publish.

Finally I highly recommend integrating one of the dependency management plugins for ANT. Life is too short to be manually resolving nested java dependencies :-)

- [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)
- [ANT Aether](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ant-aether.html)